# A bug on pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was trying to write a Binary Sorting tree when I encounter this question:
the pointer is sometimes not NULL.
In this question, the left-child of node2 is NULL.But when the pointer is compared with NULL, the result shows that it is not NULL.

And the Visual Studio 2015 raise a break:
    Raised an exception:

```
read access violation.

T is 0xCDCDCDCD.

If applicable to this exception handler, the program can safely continue to run.
```

SO how to write the if-statement to make the Display available.
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE -1 
#define NULL 0 
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* lchild, *rchild;
}BNode, *BTree;

int Display(BTree T) {
    if (T != NULL  ) {
        Display(T->lchild);
        printf("%d",T->data);
        Display(T->rchild);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else if(NULL == T){
        return FALSE;
    }
}
int main() {
    BTree node2 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node5 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node7 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node6 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node9 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node2->data = 2;
    node5->data = 5;
    node7->data = 7;
    node6->data = 6;
    node9->data = 9;
    node5->lchild = node2;
    node5->rchild = node7;
    node7->lchild = node6;
    node7->rchild = node9;

    BTree root = node5;
    Display(root);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize both `left` and `right` child with `NULL` value initially.(if any node address is not assigned to them ). This will save you from accessing garbage value.

For example:

```
node2->lchild = NULL;
node2->rchild = NULL;
```

In your case for some nodes `lchild` and `rchild` contained garbage value. And you are comparing them with `NULL`. If you thought that when you create an instance of the structure then the pointer variables are initialized with `NULL` then you were wrong.

Comment: Thank you，I think I am learning the C with a too casual manner :（，I should change my way of study，and come up with more useful question next time.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are creating a node for a list or tree always initialized it next and previous pointer to NULL. Because while you create a new pointer it holding some junk value which is not NULL and hence you need to initialized the value to NULL first. I have modified your code below please try with this:-

```
 int main() {
    BTree node2 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node5 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node7 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node6 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    BTree node9 = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    node2->data = 2;
    node5->data = 5;
    node7->data = 7;
    node6->data = 6;
    node9->data = 9;        

    node2->lchild = NULL;
    node5->lchild = NULL;
    node7->lchild = NULL;
    node6->lchild = NULL;
    node9->lchild = NULL;

    node2->rchild = NULL;
    node5->rchild = NULL;
    node7->rchild = NULL;
    node6->rchild = NULL;
    node9->rchild = NULL;

    node5->lchild = node2;
    node5->rchild = node7;
    node7->lchild = node6;
    node7->rchild = node9;

    BTree root = node5;
    Display(root);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I have already know the mistake I make and I think this question is a little bit stupid =_=.

Answer (score 1):

You ended up creating dangling or wild pointers. Make sure to always initialize pointers where you create them in your program.